# Firestore and Vue.js multiple Where clauses

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to run a query using multiple where clauses but my query ignores them. I have looked online and can not find an example to suit my needs. 
here is the code I am currently using. Any and all help is always appreciated.

```
let codeRef = db.collection('codes')
    codeRef.where('code', '==', this.code)
    codeRef.where('gid', '==', this.gid)
    codeRef.get().then(snapshot => { ...
```

Comment: Please only tag your question with technologies that are relevant to it. The question is not about the Firebase Realtime Database, and while you undoubtedly use vue.js, it seems unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try combining them?

```
let codeRef = db.collection('codes')
              .where('code','==',this.code)
              .where('gid','==',this.gid)
              .get()
```